# How to use tensorflow lite micro?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am using tensorflow lite micro to transform a .tflite model to micro controler, but when following the guide, it stoped at transforming the model to C array, but don't mention how to generate the model.cc file, I want to know how can I get the model.cc file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate the model.cc file, please follow the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers/build_convert#convert_to_a_c_array).

In short, to generate a cc file with the model data, run `xxd -i converted_model.tflite > model_data.cc`